# Не идет обновление базы данный через php

Tags: php, mysql

Код:

```
require "parts_of_site/connect_sql.php";
$priceqw = mysql_query("UPDATE Hookah_main SET PriceSort='550' WHERE ID_Hookah=30");
if($priceqw){echo "ok";}
```

Запускаю в браузере - обновление не идет. Соединение с базой есть. Если переделать запрос на вывод - данные выводятся. Если забить напрямую в скул - выполняется. В чем проблема - не пойму(

Comment: В данной формулировке ни вопрос ни ответ не имеют ценности для сообшества. Если у человека есть данная проблема то ни ваш вопрос ни ответ не найдут.. Или переформулируйте или удалите.

Comment: Мне не жалко, можно удалить. Вопрос действительно глупый, но не в этом ли его ценность? Это как первый совет в причинах поломки - "проверьте, что вилка в розетке". Если бы я наткнулся на такой ответ - то и вопрос бы не писал. Сразу бы понял куда лесть.  Про формулировку - в вопросе указаны, кажется, все условия при которых выполнялась задача. Приведен сам код. В конце концов решение тоже найдено. Не представляю, что еще можно добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Добавление не шло из-за ограниченных прав используемого пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть ошибку mysql, думаю сразу станет все ясно

```
$priceqw = mysql_query("UPDATE Hookah_main SET PriceSort='550' WHERE ID_Hookah=30") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ответ уже нашел, спасибо. Но думаю ваш способ помог бы